# How to return multiple regexp matches where the result depends on a previous match?

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0

I've been trying to match hazard codes held within a free text field. I've got a regexp that works where the codes have been entered in the format `Hxxx` where xxx is a three digit number. Easy!

However, sometimes the users have entered the first as `Hxxx` but subsequent values just as `xxx`.

So, for input data like

```
R12 34 456 / H123 H456 789 012
```

I want to match `H123` `H456` and `789` and `012`, but not the `456` before the first `H`.

Edit: To clarify, there is not a clear pattern of the data in the field. Mostly, there are some H codes, sometimes with R codes preceeding them, sometimes delimited in the example above, and sometimes not. Thus the rule I am envisaging is that three digit codes following one beginning with an `H` will be returned, but any codes not preceded by at least one H code will be ignored.

I've tried every combination of optional grouping and look-behind I can think of, and the best I've got is

```
((H|(?<=(H\d{3}\s)))\d{3}[A-Z]{0,2})
```

which matches all but the last group, but would cause problems if there were more than once space between group.

I suspect look-behind may not work anyway in an `xsl:analyze-string` command.

Is there any clever regexp trick that will work for this, or do I have to go for some more brute-force approach?

Comment: Just split the string with `/` (or get the substring after the first `/`) and then split with space or use `H?\d{3}[A-Z]{0,2}` regex

Comment: `echo "R12 34 456 / H123 H456 789 012" | cut -d/ -f2 | tr -d H`, perhaps? Or, perhaps even better, `echo "R12 34 456 / H123 H456 789 012" | cut -d/ -f2 | grep -oP '\d{3}'`.

Comment: Not sure if you are aware that look-behind (`(?<=`) is not supported in the XPath regex dialect.

Comment: It's a little bit difficult to do this from a single example of an input string. You haven't told us the general rules, e.g. is the "/" significant, will the H codes always follow the "/", do you simply want to return all tokens after the "/" regardless of the presence of an "H"?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's suggestions. I have edited the main question to clarify the pattern. Apologies for the original vagueness. I suspected that XPath didn't support lookbehind, but as I can't even get the lookbehind to do what I want it doesn't really matter too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use Saxon 9.6 or later PE and EE (for instance in oXygen or Stylus Studio) or Altova XMLSpy 2017 or Exselt and XSLT 3.0? In that case you could perhaps simply `tokenize($data, '\s+')` and use `xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with=".[matches(., 'H[0-9]{3}')]`. The following stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="matches" as="xs:string*">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="tokenize(., '\s+')"
                    group-starting-with=".[matches(., 'H[0-9]{3}')]">
                    <xsl:if test="matches(., 'H[0-9]{3}')">
                        <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each-group>               
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$matches"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms `<data>R12 34 456 / H123 H456 789 012</data>` into `<data>H123 H456 789 012</data>` so it extracts the items you are looking for.

Comment: As I am using an older version of Saxon, this needed modifying a little, by firstly converting the tokenized string into a series of nodes, but the principle worked great. It's a shame it couldn't be done as a regexp, but I've got the output I wanted now. Thanks again everyone!